# Disable Rails Form Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

So I'm trying to override a rails form using jQuery's `serialize` like so in the AJAX request:

`data : $('#update-form').serialize()`

The problem is that the form is making two requests, one via the ajax and one via the actual rails form itself.  Is there a way to make a 'dummy' form using the helpers in Rails that won't submit a request at all and leave it all to the AJAX request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lot of information in this question, but I think I can fill in the blanks. Somehow, somewhere on the form is something resembling a submit button. You must have an event listener, waiting for a click on that button. When the button is clicked, that is when you execute your code which sends the form with AJAX. If this is all true, you need to do two things:

1) Make sure that your event handler accepts the event object that will be provided.
2) `preventDefault` on that event object. This will stop the form from being submitted.

If the event handler's name was `submitForm`, the code would look like this:

```
submitForm: function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //the rest of your code
}
```